# Wordpress site hacked -- redirects to another site

Tags: wordpress

My Wordpress site has been hacked. Links on the site have been changed to take users to the hacker's site at storage.piterreceiver.ga. This site, in turn, redirects to other sites which my browser flags as dangerous.

Has anyone else had this happen? How can a restore my site and prevent a reoccurrence?

Comment: The solution is to search through all your files and remove the tags. You should also look for php files that don't belong. There is no quick fix.

Comment: One of my sites had the site and home url updated to https://storage.piterreceiver.ga/gonext/?step=1 in the database. Haven't been able to track down w=how it was done yet so if you find anything, let me know! Thanks

Comment: Please follow the steps that I have wrote at the end.

Comment: there are 3 support-topics about that (unfortunately in german: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/redirect-auf-malware-seiten/ & https://wordpress.org/support/topic/gehackt/ & https://wordpress.org/support/topic/weiterleitung-redirects/), but using a translation service may help. - there is even a zip file for a manual update, but some people doubt that everything is fixed and IMHO this should **not** be tested on a production system.

Comment: nevertheless the most professional way to would be to restore a backup (of the database and files), remove shapepress-dsgvo completely, reset **all** passwords (user, database, used mail-accounts etc.) and at least wait for the review (https://wordpress.org/plugins/shapepress-dsgvo/) to be completed.

Comment: @Richard do you have happen to have one of the plugins on this list? https://twitter.com/riper81/status/1441425259945545737?s=20

Comment: @WillingtonVega Yes I have Product Filter for WooCommerce. I had seen that article and did make sure that plugin was updated, however, the list didn't include plugins that some else I know had, who also faced the same hack. All websites I saw with it did have Woocommerce so I do believe it was either Woo or an add-on that had the vulnerability.

Comment: @WillingtonVega Just had it confirmed the other person I knew had Improved Sale Badges from that list. Looks like this is the culprit. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After all, I find the best solution, and please follow these steps:

1. Rename **wp-content** folder.
2. Create new wp-content 'don't forget about permission for this folder.
3. Install one wp security plugin like `word fence` it's recommended but you can install whatever you want.
4. Scan the whole website and directories with this plugin for Malewares.
5. For more insurance you can search the database with `mysqldump -uUSER -pPASSWORD database --extended=FALSE | grep pattern`
6. Change or delete the records found from step 4, (in my case the problem was in the `wp_options` table and `siteurl` and `home` had been changed).
7. Install a clean and fresh version of your template.
8. Copy old uploads folder from old wp-content to the new one.
9. And that's it your website will be alive again.

I just want to say thank you to @David Koenig and @Ralph Rathmann. Your replies were really helpful.

and thanks to the others for their replies and guides.

Answer (score 4):

We discovered the behaviour on several of our sites aswell, the culprit seems to be the DSGVO Plugin offered by legalweb.io.

The plugin developer has been informed and the best solution was to clean the _options from the malware code and disabled the plugin.

Comment: Thank you boidii but I did not install this plugin on my website.

Comment: It seems there are other plugins with vulnerabilities linked to the storage.piterreceiver.ga issue: https://twitter.com/riper81/status/1441425259945545737?s=20

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @Jesmond Darmanin i found the the solution how to fix that. He described to delete all occurances of "piterreceiver" in the database.
You can do that in this way:

1. Connect to your wordpress instance with SSH
2. Go to your wordpress directory
3. Execute `wp db search --all-tables piterreceiver`
4. Execute `wp db query <<< "delete from <table> where <id> = 123456"`

Be carefully, this is the "crowbar" method. Just do that, when you are absolutely sure, that the returned value is not needed anymore (which was the case in my installation < lucky guy).

Answer (score 3):

I found the same on one of my sites and could not identify any malware in the files, however, the "site URL" and "home" in "_options" table was altered and I suspect a SQL injection to have been the culprit here.
None of my malware tools could identify anything at the filesystem level so it appears to be some sort of 0day exploit as I cannot find anything similar. I've ensured that everything is updated and will monitor my site further, but a starting point would be to determine if there are any outdated plugins or themes that may suffer from a vulnerability and if yes then a more difficult task would be to identify which. I am looking through my logs now and will update this thread if I find anything.

Comment: Thanks Malin. That's the same with me. I had updated all plugins in the morning and run security plugins and manage the server firewall so I agree it's an early day exploit. The only plugin that isn't up to date, as it doesn't have a licence is YITH WooCommerce Uploads Premium. I don't suppose you have that one? Perhaps we should compare a list of plugins?

Comment: As I found it can happen with different plugins.

Comment: Hey @nima, I have reviewed as I run over 100 WordPress sites and neither experienced this issue except for one that I referenced above. It does not seem to be strictly a plugin vulnerability.

Answer (score 3):

We found this script in the WP DSGVO Tools (GDPR) Plugin by legalweb and in the Rewrite rules by YOAST SEO. But not all systems with this plugins are corupted.

Affected are mainly pages that have been updated in the last few days.

A **backup of the database** is sufficient. Nevertheless, it should be determined how the intervention in the page came about.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please tell us more details about YOAST plugin.

Comment: @nima: There was only one rewrite Rule in the table **wp_yoast_seo_links**. But only in one system. I have delete this entry.

Answer (score 3):

We saw the same behaviour on our sites and I can confirm the DSGVO plugin is the culprit. Somehow the Matomo/Google Analytics tracking codes were overwritten with the malicious redirect.

I just talked to legalweb and they confirmed that this is the underlying issue - they are working on an update but didn't want to share how the attack was performed. Disabling the plugin and looking for the redirect url in the database solved the issue.

Comment: I don't have that plugin installed, or any others by legalweb, not sure this is the same issue. Do you have Woocommerce installed? That's the common plugin I'm finding between sites I've searched, however, it's such a common plugin it could just be coincidence.

Comment: We don't use Woocommerce on our sites, so that wasn't the issue for us. As soon as I disabled the DSGVO plugin I was able to access my site. The database search was precaution to ensure nothing is left there.

Comment: That doesn't sound like the same issue. Were you seeing the storage.piterreceiver.ga/gonext/?step=1 domain everywhere? I'm not sure how disabling a plugin would return the siteurl and homeurl back to their original state.

Comment: I don't have this plugin and as I found it could be happened by any plugins or templates.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on my wp-website.

No files (.php et al) have been affected(as i can see so far), but i found in the database (wp)_options obfuscated code in "sp_dsgvo_legal_web_texts".

That points to the plugin "WP DSGVO TOOLS (GDPR)".

Since no login was possible anymore, i deleted the plugin subfolder ***shapepress-dsgvo*** via sftp on the server in the plugins-directory.

Then i deleted manually every record in the database table:

***DELETE FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` LIKE 'sp_dsgvo%'***
(maybe you have to change the table-prefix wp_ to your needs)

The Official WordPress Plugin-Directory has blocked this plugin on 20.09.21, but that doesn't affect your installation, so you have to clean it manually.

Keep in mind to find some other GDPR Tool, but for now we are happy to have a website, thats online again.

Comment: most of the people i know who were affected by the `shapepress-dsgvo`-hack could still login when directly accessing `https://domain.tld/admin` and then delete the plugin via GUI. - **if** something is left in the database or on the server, it has to be deleted manually for sure; but as i know this happened very rarely. on the other hand very few even reported, that some files were added or altered, but i clearly doubt that the `shapepress-dsgvo`-hack was the cause.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to rewrite affected files by the files from clean/original Wordpress (be sure you using the same version of the WP)

Comment: In my case, the problem was just in wp-content

Answer (score 2):

I have just managed to restore back a website that was affected by this. My fix was to search the database for **storage.piterreceiver.ga** and when found, replace it with the actual site's URL. i found two entries that needed to be amended. once that was done, i was able to get back in to Wordpress as usual.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi Jesmond, 

i have the same problem. Could you give me a tip, how to search through the whole database for that string?

Regards

Dave

Comment: If phpMyAdmin is installed, you can select you Database (not a table, but really the database) and click on the "Search" tab. Then you can enter for instance "piterreceiver" and select all tables to look up this term form. If found any, you can start cleaning the respective entries.

Comment: I found that the home and _transient_sitemap_1_rank_math_dcc1ad9d704e93b982972a85d7ec91ba.xml entries in the wp_options table in the database had been changed to include storage.piterreceiver.ga. Others suggested that the DSGVO plugin was at fault, but I am not using that.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, the problem is about the plugin WP DSGVO Tools (GDPR) and in our case, the database entry could also be deleted in the backend, by navigating to /wp-admin/admin.php?page=sp-dsgvo&tab=statistic-integrations > Matomo > Use Matomo (off) or removing the content from the field "Matomo code".

Answer (score 0):

I scanned my wp-website with sucuri.net and had some high risk malware alert. When I tried to enter my site it directed me to this 'storage.piterreceiver.ga' and '0.johncarlsberg.best' (also with 1,2 etc. as prefix).
Because I also wasn't able to restore my updraftBackup, because I got some authentication errors, I tried uninstalling Plugins and updating everything.

-> For me it fixed the site by uninstalling WP DSGVO Tools (GDPR) Plugin.